# Checking Principal-user by Injected SecurityContext inside the constructor of a web resource

Tags: jersey, jax-rs

I'm relatively new to Jersey and JAX-RS, but I can't find my way in the documentation about the use of the SecurityContext inside the constructor of a Resource.

Our OAUTH implementation is currently such that all requests on the REST API are intercepted by an implementation of the ResourceFilter. So the resource filter sets a user Principal by calling:

```
containerRequest.setSecurityContext(new MySecurityContext(user));
```

... inside the ContainerRequest.filter() method, wWith a concrete class MySecurityContext, as:

```
public class MySecurityContext implements SecurityContext {

    private final User principal;

    public MySecurityContext(final User user) {
        this.principal = user;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAuthenticationScheme() {
        return SecurityContext.FORM_AUTH;
    }

    @Override
    public Principal getUserPrincipal() {
        return principal;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSecure() {
        return false;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isUserInRole(String role) {
        return principal.getRoles().contains(role);
    }
}
```

Now I want to use that user principal in the constructor of the webresource before any @GET/@POST/@DELETE method is called. I've tried injecting

```
@Context SecurityContext
```

..into the constructor argument list but a call to getUserPrincipal() just yields null.

Is there a way to check the Principal user in the constructor of a Webresource?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It works for me if I inject it into my API endpoint:

```
@POST
@ResourceFilters({MyAuthenticationFilter.class})
public Response foo(@Context HttpServletRequest request, @Context SecurityContext security) {
    final Principal principal = security.getUserPrincipal();
    [...]
    return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).build();
}
```